# Firebase Custom Authentication passing tokens

Tags: go, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am running a Go server that generates JWT tokens. My original plan was to send the tokens using an http.Redirect using the token string as part of the url.

This doesn't appear to work because I'm using Firebase static hosting and hence only have client side routing.

How can I push my token? Headers maybe?

- I'm running my **static** SPA on 'example.firebaseapp.com' (A).
- I'm running my server that **generates tokens** on 'example.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' (B)
- The **cas server** is running on 'https://login.example.edu/cas/' (C)
- There is also of course the user's computer (D)

The flow goes as follows

1. User load website from static host (A)
2. User on computer D clicks 'login through school' button and is directed to my server (B)
3. B then redirects to cas server (C). User puts in his credentials and is redirected to computer B.
4. Computer B then generates a token using a secret key and a uid.
5. **This token needs to somehow be set back to the user**
   User would then call `ref.authWithCustomToken("AUTH_TOKEN", function(error, authData) {`

### Go Server Code

```
    func (h *myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      if !cas.IsAuthenticated(r) {
        cas.RedirectToLogin(w, r)
        return
      }

    if r.URL.Path == "/logout" {
        cas.RedirectToLogout(w, r)
        return
    }

  generatedToken := generateToken("uid") // token is created using a uid and a secret
    redirectURL := websiteURL + generatedToken
    println(redirectURL)

    println(generatedToken)
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, http.StatusFound) // I attempt to send the token using a redirect. This doesn't seem to work though since the static server only supports routing for '/'. 
    //html.WriteTo(w)

    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Where do you run your Go server? How are you trying to pass the token? Showing code of a [minimal, complete reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem may go a long way to clarify.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my post. I am running my go server on AWS. I am passing the token through the URL which does work but the static server doesnt recognize the url since it doesn't have routing for it. The formatting of the code is a bit messed up not sure why - feel free it edit my post if you'd like.

Comment: @ChrisW, did you ever get this figured out?  I'm curious what you ended up going with because I am thinking about this exact same workflow.  We also use CAS for our central authentication.

Comment: Yeah! I followed what Frank said. I passed the token through the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the flow correctly, then what you're missing is an end point that your app user talks to and that can return the token to that user.

A workaround for this would be to have the user app pass in a highly unguessable value (a "request ID") in step 2, something like a UUID. The token server can then write the token into the Firebase Database in step 5 in `/tokens/<requestID>`, where the client is listening for it.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out